# Rotating an object locally in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-engine

[image]

[image]

As seen in the photo, when I rotate an object, the y-axis changes, I don't want this to happen.
Since the y axis has changed, when I want to rotate the object on the y axis again, it does not rotate correctly.
I need to turn the object locally.
What can I do in this situation?

Comment: Are you speaking about code or in the editor Scene View? You can simply switch the handles between local and global axis mode via the toolbar .. see [Positioning GameObjects -> Gizmo Handle Position Toggles](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PositioningGameObjects.html)

Comment: When I want to change the rotation for the second time on the code side, the axes are differentiated. This problem goes away when I change the rotation globally but I can't get the rotation I want.

Comment: If this is about code then please share your code ...

Comment: mainObject.transform.DOLocalRotate(desiredAngle,1,RotateMode.LocalAxisAdd);

This code rotating the object 90 degrees at a time on a single axis. However, after each rotate, the axes changing, for example, the Y axis becomes the Z axis.

Comment: Is this using DoTween or something? There is no built-in thing called `DOLocalRotate` ... And as the name says .. yeah this seems to use **local space** .. if you don't want to do that then there is for sure also something like `DORotate` which uses always the same global space ...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, a solution could be to create an empty game object with the same position as the one you're rotating, and attaching the object you're rotating as a child to the empty game object which will act as the parent game object, so rotating the child object will give you local rotation and rotating the parent object will give global rotation.

Hope this makes sense :D